# Faulty API request in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, bad-request, axios-retry

I'm working on a challenge that is using a faulty API. I'm really struggling to get any data back from the GET request only this error:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Unsupported protocol  https:', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}}
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
message: "Unsupported protocol  https:"
name: "AxiosError"
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

I'm not sure how to get and data back and to store it so I can display something on the client page when the api is faulting.
My Postman GET request works 9 out of 10 times but never seems to work while the app is running.

Postman data:

```
{
    "Provider": "Film World",
    "Movies": [
        {
            "ID": "fw2488496",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Harrison Ford, Mark Hamill, Carrie Fisher, Adam Driver",
            "Price": 25
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw2527336",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ1MzcxNjg4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzgwMjY4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Mark Hamill, Carrie Fisher, Adam Driver, Daisy Ridley",
            "Price": 24.5
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw2527338",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IX - The Rise of Skywalker",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDljNTQ5ODItZmQwMy00M2ExLTljOTQtZTVjNGE2NTg0NGIxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODkzNTgxMDg@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Carrie Fisher, Mark Hamill, Adam Driver, Daisy Ridley",
            "Price": 23.5
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw3748528",
            "Title": "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEwMzMxODIzOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzg3OTAzMDI@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Felicity Jones, Diego Luna, Alan Tudyk, Donnie Yen",
            "Price": 28
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw3778644",
            "Title": "Solo: A Star Wars Story",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTM2NTI3NTc3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzM1OTQyNTM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Alden Ehrenreich, Joonas Suotamo, Woody Harrelson, Emilia Clarke",
            "Price": 24
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw0076759",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00Y2Y3LWE3ZjctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Peter Cushing",
            "Price": 22.9
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw0080684",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00NjZmLTg5NGItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Billy Dee Williams",
            "Price": 23.7
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw0086190",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00Y2IzLTk1NTMtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Billy Dee Williams",
            "Price": 22
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw0120915",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRhNjcwNWQtMGJmMi00NmQyLWE2YzItODVmMTdjNWI0ZDA2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Liam Neeson, Ewan McGregor, Natalie Portman, Jake Lloyd",
            "Price": 27.2
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw0121765",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDAzM2M0Y2UtZjRmZi00MzVlLTg4MjEtOTE3NzU5ZDVlMTU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Ewan McGregor, Natalie Portman, Hayden Christensen, Christopher Lee",
            "Price": 19.9
        },
        {
            "ID": "fw0121766",
            "Title": "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
            "Actors": "Ewan McGregor, Natalie Portman, Hayden Christensen, Ian McDiarmid",
            "Price": 22.4
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code that is returning the console error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(" https://challenge.lexicondigital.com.au/api/v2/filmworld/movies", {
        headers: {
          "x-api-key": "Yr2636E6BTD3UCdleMkf7UEdqKnd9n361TQL9An7",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

Comment: _`.get(" https://...`_ just a typo. Remove the space before `https` in the URL